# Checking integer tuples for binary conditions efficiently

Tags: python, combinations, combinatorics, bitmask

I am writing a piece of code which takes 5 lists of integers (`ships`), a bitmask (`hits`) and outputs the number of 5-tuples (one integer from each list) that are consistent with the following two conditions:

A. No two integers in the tuple have set bits in the same position.

B. All set bits in the bitmask must also be set among the integers in the tuple.

I have the following solution which works:

```
def noCollisionsBin(v, hits):
    tot = 0
    for i in v:
        if tot & i:
            return False
        tot |= i
    return (tot & hits) == hits

hits = 4224
ships = [[16777216,8388608,4194304,2097152,1048576,524288,262144,131072,65536,32768,16384,8192,4096,2048,1024,512,256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1],[25165824,17301504,12582912,540672,6291456,16896,3145728,528,786432,8650752,393216,270336,196608,8448,98304,264,24576,4325376,12288,135168,6144,4224,3072,132,768,2162688,384,67584,192,2112,96,66,24,1081344,12,33792,6,1056,3,33],[16777216,8388608,4194304,2097152,1048576,524288,262144,131072,65536,32768,16384,8192,4096,2048,1024,512,256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1],[25165824,17301504,12582912,540672,6291456,16896,3145728,528,786432,8650752,393216,270336,196608,8448,98304,264,24576,4325376,12288,135168,6144,4224,3072,132,768,2162688,384,67584,192,2112,96,66,24,1081344,12,33792,6,1056,3,33],[16777216,8388608,4194304,2097152,1048576,524288,262144,131072,65536,32768,16384,8192,4096,2048,1024,512,256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]]

i=0
for ship1 in ships[0]:
    for ship2 in ships[1]:
        for ship3 in ships[2]:
            for ship4 in ships[3]:
                for ship5 in ships[4]:
                    if noCollisionsBin((ship1, ship2, ship3, ship4, ship5), hits):
                        i+=1

print(i) # Correctly outputs 1188564
```

However, instead of generating all possible tuples and checking the two conditions for each tuple, I would like to exclude invalid tuples more efficiently, for example by taking two integers and discarding the combination if they have set bits in the same position (thus violating condition A) before proceeding to check condition B.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
i=0

tot = 0
for ship1 in ships[0]:
    if (ship1 & tot):
        continue
    tot |= ship1
    for ship2 in ships[1]:
        if (ship2 & tot):
            continue
        tot |= ship2
        for ship3 in ships[2]:
            if (ship3 & tot):
                continue
            tot |= ship3
            for ship4 in ships[3]:
                if (ship4 & tot):
                    continue
                tot |= ship4
                for ship5 in ships[4]:
                    if (ship5 & tot):
                        continue
                    tot |= ship5
                    if (tot & hits) == hits:
                        i+=1

print(i) # incorrectly outputs 8
```

What am I doing wrong?

(PS. A recursive way of getting rid of the nested loops so it works for n lists of integers would also be great!)

Comment: You can replace your nested loops with `itertools.product`.

Comment: @Samwise How would you do the desired short-circuiting with that?

Comment: The short-circuiting doesn't work with `product` as-is.  However, you could look at the sample implementation in the `product` doc, copy it, and add your short-circuiting to that.

Comment: I tried tweaking ```itertools.product``` earlier, but I couldn't get the short-circuiting to work! Perhaps I didn't try hard enough :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only ever `|=` to your `tot`, you never undo it. You could use `tot1`, `tot2`, etc, for example like:

```
tot1 = ship1
  ...
    tot2 = tot1 | ship2
      ...
```

A perhaps better solution, inspired by Samwise's suggestion to reuse the sample implementation of `itertools.product` in its doc:

```
from collections import Counter

tots = Counter([0])
for shipp in ships:
    tots2 = Counter()
    for tot, freq in tots.items():
        for ship in shipp:
            if not tot & ship:
                tots2[tot | ship] += freq
    tots = tots2
print(sum(freq for tot, freq in tots.items() if tot & hits == hits))
```

For me that's about three times faster than your fixed second solution.

Comment: That's it, thank you! Improved the runtime for the given input (where three of the lists were identical) by a factor of five!

Comment: @user6353 Added another solution now, how fast is that for you?

Comment: @user6353 Its `tots` is just a Counter of all tots possible and how often they occurred. Initially it's just the single tot `0`, but then for each additional ship, the possibilities increase (by combining the possibilities before considering that ship, with the list for that ship).

Comment: Wow, it's ridiculously fast. For a worst case input (where all the lists are identical), using time.time() I got the following results:

Original (brute force) solution: 41.0 s
Fixed second solution:              4.03 s
Third solution:                            0.22 s